# Getting rid of square brackets on either side of a string

Tags: python, regex

I am importing currency exchange rates from a website.  All is well, except python prints the required data as follows:

```
['12.3098']
```

which means I can't use the data that I scraped in any calculations in my program. How do I get rid of the square brackets so that I can convert the string inside the square brackets to a float?

Comment: that is a list not a string, `float(['12.3098'][0])`, if it was a string `float(['12.3098'][1:-1])`  or `float(['12.3098']).strip("[]")`

Comment: Is that actually the value of the string, or do you have a list? Show the code that generates this value and performs the printout.

Comment: You probably got this result by using `findall()`. It always returns a list of the results, even if there's only one.

Answer (score 2):

you have a list which is not a string... so if you want to get that value out select it like so

```
float(result[0])
```

replace 'result' with whatever your object is, aka what you printed `['12.3098']`

try printing the type of your object `type(result)` and if its a list then this will fix your problem

if the type is a string you can do a literal evaluation of it like this

```
import ast
result = ast.literal_eval(result)
print result[0]
```

Comment: This is not necessarily true: `s = "['12.3098']"; print(s)`. (Though it is likely.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell considering the OP is getting this result from a web request, its highly unlikely that that response would return a literal string with brackets and quotes inside... I guess its possible.. but I added a way to test if its actually a list first just incase